# PSQL - Not returning null columns after left join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to do an aggregation that counts total sales amounts grouped by hour. I need to return all hours within the last 24 hours, regardless if they have sales or not, and include the sales that happened within that hour.

To do this I'm doing `GENERATE_SERIES` like so...

```
SELECT * FROM GENERATE_SERIES(
  date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp - interval '23 hour'),
  date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp),
  '1 hour'
)
```

This returns the following rows

```
generate_series
------------------------
 2017-09-17 16:00:00-07
 2017-09-17 17:00:00-07
 2017-09-17 18:00:00-07
 2017-09-17 19:00:00-07
 2017-09-17 20:00:00-07
 2017-09-17 21:00:00-07
 2017-09-17 22:00:00-07
 2017-09-17 23:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 00:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 01:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 02:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 03:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 04:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 05:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 06:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 07:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 08:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 09:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 10:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 11:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 12:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 13:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 14:00:00-07
 2017-09-18 15:00:00-07
(24 rows)
```

This is good so far. Now I want to join with my orders table to get the numbers. I'm doing this...

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('hour', orders.ordered_at) as hour,
  COALESCE(SUM(orders.total), 0) AS price,
  #{merchant.id} AS merchant_id
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(
  date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp - interval '23 hour'),
  date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp),
  '1 hour'
) AS h
LEFT JOIN orders
  ON date_trunc('hour', orders.ordered_at) = h
  AND orders.merchant_id = merchant_id
GROUP BY hour
ORDER BY hour DESC;
```

When I run this I get this...

```
hour         |  price  | merchant_id
---------------------+---------+-------------
                     |       0 |           1
 2017-09-18 09:00:00 | 2934.00 |           1
(2 rows)
```

2 Questions...

1 - Why do I have a NULL hour

2 - Where did all my other hours go? I'm expecting 24 rows where one row has price and the others have 0 for price

Answer (score 1):

Your `NULL` hour is because you are pulling it from the wrong table.  Instead, use:

```
SELECT gs.hh, COALESCE(SUM(o.total), 0) AS price,
       #{merchant.id} AS merchant_id
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp - interval '23 hour'),
                     date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp),
                     '1 hour'
                    ) gs(hh) LEFT JOIN
      orders o
      ON date_trunc('hour', o.ordered_at) = gs.hh AND
         o.merchant_id = merchant_id
GROUP BY gs.hh
ORDER BY gs.hh DESC;
```

I would guess that you also want your `ON` clause to be:

```
ON o.merchant_id = #{merchant.id}
```

Because `o.merchant_id = merchant_id` should be interpreted as `o.merchant_id = o.merchant_id`.

Comment: aha! Thank you! FYI - your answer has one typo. Should be `COALESCE(SUM(o.total)`